# How does NetCut work?

Tags: networking, local-area-network

NetCut is a software which enables a network admin to turn off the internet connection of any machine in a LAN.
I want to know how it works. It has something to do with spurious ARP packets, however can't seem to find exactly how it works. I am looking for a detailed answer.
Any takers ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd guess it's using [ARP Spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing). It won't just limit internet traffic, but all traffic trying to get to that machine. Also, there's a requirement that both machines need to be the same broadcast domain. It's really a broken way to limit internet access, though. If you want do to this the right way, do it at the firewall and/or proxy level.

Additionally, if you really want to figure out what it's doing, just fire up [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), and do a packet capture while you're running the software.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ErikA's points against the use of things like **NetCut** (+1 there).
As an additional reference, you might want to look at [**Anti-NetCut2**](http://www.tools4free.net/).
It also has some basics in a link called [Lessons](http://www.tools4free.net/lessons.htm).

Other references,

1. [NetCut at arcai](http://www.arcai.com/)
2. [Protect Your Computer Against ARP Poison Attack netCut](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/08/07/protect-your-computer-against-arp-poison-attack-netcut/)
   Refers [AntiARP](http://www.antiarp.com/english.html) on a Chinese site (at your risk :)